# How can I override this inline styling?

Tags: css, iframe, notion

I want to remove the annoying black border from the Twitter feed in the right column on this page:

https://radix.wiki/ecosystem/listings/radit

The ID of the element is #bodyTag so I've thrown the book at it with:

```
body#bodyTag[style] { background-color: transparent !important }
```

but it's unresponsive.